# C# regex (coming from a perl/javascript background)

Tags: c#, regex, regex-greedy

This match is giving me no matches, seemingly no matter what:

```
static String divine(int n)
{
    if (n % 3 == 0) { return String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("5", n).ToArray()); }

    String res = String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(" ", n));
    Regex ItemRegex = new Regex(@"^(\\s{3}){0,}(\\s{5})*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Match match = ItemRegex.Match(res);
```

But this PCRE regex is behaving perfectly at regex101.com: `^(\s{3}){0,}(\s{5})*$`

It always greedily matches the small group (sets of 3), and matches the large group only as needed to have no spaces unmatched at the end.

My question is, what do I have to do to get the regex to behave as expected in c#? If I had to guess, at this point I am leaning towards `{,}` maybe being illegal? I don't know.

Comment: Regex rule is unclear. Could you elaborate with some examples ?

Comment: One reason is `{0,}` and `*` at end and it's matching lazily here. So you asking for **layness** at two places. Since `*` means `zero` or more. It's taking zero for `{0,}` and for `*` too, thus matching nothing.

Comment: you can add it to regex101.com and then just start pressing the space bar to change the length of the string. It should not match until 3 spaces, then not match, then match the right side at 5 spaces. Not match at 7, and after that fall into a pattern with 0,1 or 2 matches on the right side and the rest a match on the left side.

Comment: @noob — thanks. that's fine — so C# handles regexes differently. How do we get the behavior seen with this regex in _regex101.com_ (or perl, javascript, etc) translated into C#'s regex engine?

Comment: I don't think it's about C# handling it differently. You regex is designed so that it will match even `nothing`. Not me but [this demo talking](https://regex101.com/r/vZ8pN1/1). `1 Match in 7 Steps`.

Comment: interestingly enough, your link is just the regex101 — the place I already have verified it. I can post a screenshot if you like .. on my screen when I follow your link and don't put input, I don't get a match, contrary to your claim. It works otherwise, for every case it should work. I have verified this through several dozen space bar presses, out of boredom :) luckily, @Laurel had the answer, so its no big deal.

Comment: I don't see how you didn't got a match. [Screenshot](https://beta.postimg.org/image/nopl7ngxj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see Java's influence. The `@` means you do not need the evil escaped escape `\\`:

`@"^(\s{3}){0,}(\s{5})*$"`

In case you didn't know, Java's regexes are a pain. Most languages aren't like that. Python, for example, uses `r` instead of C#'s `@`.

---

Edit: JavaScript only makes you escape escapes within strings, but you can use something like: `var word2 = word.replace(/\s/g, "");`.  The syntax is similar to Perl, actually.

Java has no alternative to escaped escapes, which is why I assumed you meant Java.

Comment: JavaScript, too.  If you create the regex in the form of a string literal, you have to double escape, same as in Java.